# how to assign number to following characters "@" or "#" or "^" and "*"

Tags: c++, mapping

I am a new c++ student, and am working on a problem that requires that I assign a number to special characters.

The exercise asks to set the characters @ to 2, # to 3, ^ to 4, and * to 5. For example, if a user enters @#^*, it should be identical to entering (2+3+4+5).

Thank you, John.

Comment: Have you tried a state machine?

Comment: Use a switch to map your characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple character array:

```
static const char symbols[] = {'@', '#', '^', '*'};
char c;
std::cin >> c;
unsigned int value;
for (value = 0; value < sizeof(symbols); ++value)
{
  if (c == symbols[value])
  {
    break;
  }
}
if (value >= sizeof(symbols))
{
  // Symbol not found.
}
else
{
  value += 2;
}
```

The above code searches the array of characters for the symbol.  If the symbol exist, the index is the value associated with the symbol.  However, since the `@` symbol is first and the array indices start at 0, an adjustment is made by adding 2 to the array index after the value is found.

**Edit 1: Lookup table**
Another method is to use a lookup table.  Create a structure containing the relationship, then make an array of those structures.

```
struct Relationship
{
  char  c;
  unsigned int value;
};

Relationship table[] = 
{
  {'@', 2}, {'#', 3}, {'^', 4}, {'*', 5},
};
const unsigned int TABLE_SIZE =
    sizeof(table) / sizeof(table[0]);

char c;
cin >> c;
unsigned int value = 0;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; ++i)
{
    if (table[i].c == c)
    {
      value = table[i].value;
      break;
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:  Using `switch`**
Another method is to use the `switch` statement:

```
char c = '\0';
cin >> c;
unsigned int value;
switch (c)
{
    case '@': value = 2; break;
    case '#': value = 3; break;
    case '^': value = 4; break;
    case '*': value = 5; break;
    default: value = 0; break;
}
```

**The if/else ladder:**
**Edit 3: The program:**

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;


int main(void)
{
    cout << "Enter symbol: ";
    char c;
    cin >> c;
    unsigned int value = 0U;
    if (c == '@')
    {
      value = 2;
    }
    else if (c == '#')
    {
      value = 3;
    }
    else if (c == '^')
    {
      value = 4;
    }
    else if (c == '*')
    {
      value = 5;
    }
    else
    {
      value = 0;
    }

    cout << "\nYour value: " << value;
    return 0;
}
```

Sample run:

```
C:\Debug>symbol_matching.exe
Enter symbol: @

Your value: 2
C:\Debug>symbol_matching.exe
Enter symbol: *

Your value: 5
C:\Debug>symbol_matching.exe
Enter symbol: ^

Your value: 4
C:\Debug>symbol_matching.exe
Enter symbol: #

Your value: 3
```

*Note:  I typed the special symbol, then pressed Enter.*

Comment: I tried using the "if/else ladder". When enter the special character i get a 00 as a return. ei: cin >> c; cout << "you enter " << c << value << endl;. The return is: you enter 00. What i am doing wrong?

Comment: See my changes with **Edit 3**.  I have no idea where you placed your statements.

Answer (score 4):

A `std::map<char, int>` may do what you need.

Comment: Upvoted for the excellent guess that the OP probably means "mapping" when he says "assigning".

Comment: IT would be overwhelming for a new student though

Comment: Not only it would be overwhelming, but inefficient, too.